# how to click a button on webpage having class name using vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am a rookie in VBA excel.
There is a web page application in which
i need to click a button, the source of which is

```
<em class="x-btn-arow" unselectable="on">
<button class= x-btn-text" id="ext-gen7576" style=""   type="button">Actions</button>

Sub xx()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim l As IHTMLElement
Dim lo As IHTMLElementCollection




Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://theapplicationlink"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4



Set doc = IE.Document
Set lo = doc.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each l In lo
If l.getAttribute("class") = "x-btn-text" Then
l.click



End If
Next

End Sub
```

it doesn't throw any error but it doesn't click the button.

I cannot use ID as it keeps on changing each time i launch the application.
Also the class and type is same for other buttons also.

Forgive me for any technical errors
Any help will be a huge favour here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"button" is not a HTML tag. use a "Tag". let me give you an example here. Replace the "strTagName" with a HTML tage that inlcudes the thing you want to click.

```
Dim objTag As Object
For Each objTag In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName(strTagName)
    If InStr(objTag.outerHTML, "x-btn-text") > 0 Then

        objTag.Click
        Exit For

    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an id. Does it change completely or does part of it remain the same? If it were you could partial match on the bit that remain the same using a CSS selector.

That aside you could  use:

```
objIE.document.querySelector("button[class*= x-btn-text]").Click
```

This uses a CSS selector to target the element of `button[class*= x-btn-text]`. Which will be the first element with `button` tag having attribute `class` with value containing  `x-btn-text`.

Comment: If there is another button next to it with the same class?? i should type querySelector("button[class*= x-btn-text]")(1) ?

Comment: Depends if selector still works. You would also need querySelectorAll(selector).item(1)